# How to make react grid crousel responsive

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am making one grid crousel, It is working fine in laptop and desktop but is not responsive when check in Tablet and mobile. The main issue which i am facing is like when load the crousel with Tablet and mobile screen then found in the crousel left and right button is got hidden. I tried to override the css to make it responsive but since It used styled component i could not find there any specific class to have it done.

Below is my code:

```
import Carousel from "react-grid-carousel";

  const KpiCarousel = (props: IKpiCarouselProps) => {
  const [kpis, setKpis] = useState<Kpi[]>([]);
  const [cols, setCols] = useState(3);
  const carouselRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (kpis) {
      setKpis(KpiService.KPIs(props.caseStats, props.settings));
    }
  }, [props.caseStats, props.settings]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver((event) => {
      const width = event[0].contentBoxSize[0].inlineSize;
      setCols(Math.floor(width / 240));
    });

    if (carouselRef) {
      resizeObserver.observe(carouselRef.current);
    }
  }, [carouselRef]);

  const canAddMore: boolean = kpis.filter((f) => !f.visible).length > 0;

  return (
    <div ref={carouselRef} style={{ width: "100%", maxHeight: "160px" }}>
      <StyledCarousel cols={cols} rows={1} gap={6} showDots={true}>
        {kpis
          .filter((f) => f.visible)
          .map((item, i) => (
            <Carousel.Item key={i}>
              <KpiTile kpi={item} />
            </Carousel.Item>
          ))}
        {canAddMore && (
          <Carousel.Item key="add-more">
            <AddMetricTile onAddMetric={props.onAddMetric} />
          </Carousel.Item>
        )}
      </StyledCarousel>
    </div>
  );
};
```

When i tried to change the screen then at one level it looks fine like below:

[image: WorkingImage]

But when decrease screen size then crousel content is not in sync and the left button is hidden:

[image: Not working Image]

Need help.